# Setting a cv::Mat to its maximum possible value

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using opencv through the C++ interface. I know that I can use `cv::Mat::operator=(const Scalar& s)` or `cv::Mat::setTo()` to set a `cv::Mat` to a specific value. But how can I set a `cv::Mat` passed as parameter to my function to its maximum possible value?

Comment: How do you define it's maximum possible value? I can't understand exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Please, give more details?

Comment: The maximum possible value of a `cv::Mat` depends on its depth and number of channels, for example a `cv::Mat` with a single channel and depth CV_32S should have as maximum value the biggest signed integer.

Comment: So, you want to set all channels to the biggest int,float,char, depending on the type? I don't think such a functionality exists, you will need to implement it yourself.

Comment: Well I ask because I haven't found such a function. But something like the macro `CV_MAKE_TYPE(depth, cn)`, which given the depth and the number of channels creates a type, could exist to get the maximum value.

Answer (score 4):

First, it depends on what type of your matrix is, 8UC1 is 8 bit unsigned char, max is 255. 32SC1's max value is max integer value if I recalled correctly, max 64FC1 is max double value.

Normally I'd do something like this.

```
/* Test with small matrix */
cv::Mat matrix_1( 2, 2, CV_32FC3, Scalar::all( std::numeric_limits<float>::max() ) );

/* Subsequent assigment is something like this */
matrix_1 = Scalar::all( std::numeric_limits<float>::max() );

cout << matrix_1 << endl;

/* Test with integer matrix */
cv::Mat matrix_2( 2, 2, CV_32SC2, Scalar::all( std::numeric_limits<int>::max() ) );

/* Subsequent assigment is something like this */
matrix_2 = Scalar::all( std::numeric_limits<int>::max() );

cout << matrix_2 << endl;
```

If it's 8UC type, then just use 255, if it's 64FC type, then use double type.

Comment: That can be accomplished when you know the type of the `cv::Mat` at compile time. But what happen when you don't know that type at compile time; because of this case I told in my question that I was receiving the `cv::Mat` as a parameter of my function.

Comment: matrix_1.type() should return you the type. Then use a switch to handle the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty late to party, but anyways:

I just tried solving the exact same problem, and using [elemSize1()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a9acde8f32d4b294558fb406bc05171bc) works.

`cv::pow(2, 8*src->elemSize1())-1` gives the max greyvalue of a given cv::Mat.